# AutoMapper IgnoreAllTheRest capabilities

Tags: c#, automapper

I am new to AutoMapper and wanting to setup for two properties to map but the other 15 ignore.

My research and reading such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337883/automapper-ignore-all-items-of-ienumerableselectlistitem) indicates 3 options.

1. Use Ignore() such as: (currently do and it works but is bloated)

   ```
   d => d.IgnoreMe, opt => opt.Ignore()
   ```
2. Annotate with [IgnoreMapAttribute]. Wish I could but the object is not mine to tweak.
3. Extension Method such as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663771/how-to-use-ignore-globally-in-automapper) answer posted by [Rami A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90287/rami-a)(I would have to tweak it)

However it seemed to me these options are work arounds and I am just not using AutoMapper properly?

What I am looking for is something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, DropPointModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId,
                 opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.VendorId,
                 opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.VendorId))
      .IgnoreAllOtherMappings();
```

Does something along these lines exist in AutoMapper and I'm not implementing correctly or am I correct and just need to write the extension method. If the latter I will post back here for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate question to another and I am not going to provide the answer here as the original author(s) need credit for their work.

Check it out here and be sure to upvote if it helped.

[AutoMapper: "Ignore the rest"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using somethin like the following

```
public static class MappingExpressionExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> IgnoreAllUnmapped<TSource, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> expression)
    {
        expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
        return expression;
    }
}

      .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.VendorId,
                      opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.VendorId))
        .IgnoreAllUnmapped();
```

or this

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.VendorId,
                      opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.VendorId))
      .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: See I figured I wasn't understanding correctly. My understanding of ForAllMembers was that it would apply to all member retroactively so the previous two mappings (CustomerId & VendorId) would be ignored.

Comment: and as a follow up testing ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Ignore()) does indeed retroactively ignore everything.

Comment: your answer is a good one if we reverse the order. Do the ignore first then do the specific mappings.